# How to get text of this element not the child

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to hide the text `First Text` only, using (`opacity:0`) when I mouse over the `topblock`.

```
<div class="topblock">
   First Text
   <div class="block">
      Inner Text
   </div>
</div>
```

But I When i use following jQuery code i am getting child DIV text also `First Text Inner Text`

```
$(".topblock").on("mouseenter",function(){
    console.log($(this).text());
    $(this).css({"opacity":"0"})
}).on("mouseleave",function(){

});
```

Comment: Changing opacity will make all inner elements change opacity. You would have these blocks separated in a container div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do what you require without amending the HTML structure will be exceptionally difficult as you would need to amend the `textNode` holding the `First text` value directly.

Instead it would be far simpler to just amend your HTML to wrap that text in another element, such as a `span`, and perform the operations on that element. Try this:

```
<div class="topblock">
   <span>First Text</span>
   <div class="block">
      Inner Text
   </div>
</div>
```

```js
$(".topblock").on("hover",function(){
    $(this).find('span').toggle();
});
```

Comment: Yes it solved my problem. Generally Asking, How can I do some operation on the `topblock` contents excluding Inner Text  (without inner span)

Comment: Using the method above, you can just target the `span`, as per my example. If you can't amend the HTML you would need to get the textNode, and wrap it in a `span` programmatically. To get the textNode: `$('.topblock').contents().filter(function() { return this.nodeType == 3; }).first()`. You'd then need to `wrap()` and `hide()` or `show()` it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just hide a part of a block. You can put `First text` in a span and hide the span when your mouse enter the topblock block

Answer (score 1):

Impossible to do using `opacity`, but you could accomplish it by setting the `color` to match the background color on hover.

Here's how to achieve the effect while hovering `.topblock` *except* when hovering its `.block` child.  Note the use of CSS `!important`:

```js
$('.topblock').hover(
  function() {
    $(this).addClass('white');
  },
  function() {
    $(this).removeClass('white');
  });

$('.block').hover(
  function() {
    $('.topblock').addClass('black');
  },
  function() {
    $('.topblock').removeClass('black');
  });
```

```css
.topblock .block, .black {
  color: black !important;
}

.white {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="topblock">
   First Text
   <div class="block">
      Inner Text
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is Hover over the 'Inner Text' is also hiding the First Text. Is it possible to make the Hover executable only on First Text? I think we need a span as suggested by @MatthieuLemoine & others

Comment: Adding a span certainly simplifies things, but I've updated my answer with a solution that works without doing so.